# Solve: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, sockets

I understand there have been many solutions for this, but NONE of them work. I have searched through over 50 PAGES on google and I can not find a solution that will work. Please I am begging, anyone that can help or has any idea, PLEASE I'm having figurative suicidal thoughts.

Solved: I just did apt-get purge MySQL; apt-get install mysql

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read this post first http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. And post some code that you wrote so far

Comment: you need to document this like 5 times more. We have almost nothing to work with here.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I just did apt-get purge MySQL; apt-get install mysql – 5A13X99